# Contribution of a sample to cross validation error

Tags: cross-validation, bias

I was wondering how to asses which sample in the data, during K fold cross-validation drives the bias that may be observed in the results.

My training data consists of 40 samples. And I try to classify these samples based on some class that i know using PLSDA.  I perform 10 fold stratified cross-validation a 100 times and identify the optimal parameter.

I find that there is some bias based on how the data is split, and would like to understand which are the samples in the test-fold, that drive the bias.

For this, I keep track of how my data is split across ten folds, and for each test fold, I also keep track of the error. I then count the number of times a patient was in  a test fold that gave me the least error or the greatest error when compared to other folds. And try to come up with a metric based on this frequency as a measure of contribution to bias...

But, each fold consists of 4 patients, and the final metric I get may not reflect the individual contribution. Any thoughts on this would be helpful.

Comment: I'd consider the changes in model due to diffent splits an indicator of variance, i.e. the models are unstable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider a leave-one-patient-out jackknifing scheme instead of leaving out 4 patients, you can easiy calculate [Cook's Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%27s_distance) which is a measure of leverage for each of the patients.